# Distributing IOS apps unlimited outside of app store

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa, in-house-distribution

We have a problem distributing our IOS application, because unfortunately App Store is not available in our country. Is there any method to distribute our application outside of App Store without organization limitation of in-house program?
Thanks for your feed backs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a enterprise program https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/how-to-distribute-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-ios-enterprise-program-a871/

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you these 2 options:

- [daivi](https://www.diawi.com) - Pros: Easy to use
- [AppCenter](https://www.diawi.com) - Pros: Microsoft...